# Count values in columns with condition referencing las column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have little question.

So i have a a df like this:

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0.3, 0, 0.6], [3, 0, 0.74, 0, 0.25], [4, 1, 0.9, 0, 0],  [5, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ID", "annotation", "S1", 'S2', 'S3'])
df
```

I need to count the number of values > min_specificity & df['annotation'] == 0, by column. where min_specificity = 0.90.

desired output:

```
data = [['S1', 1], ['S2', 0], ['S3', 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["sample", "count"])
df
```

Why?

because for S1 the ID 1 is higher in values than min_specifity =0.9 and the it has a df['annotation] = 0. The ID 4 has a higher value than min_specificity but df['annotation'] = 1. and so on.

I was thinking about something like:

```
df = df[(df >= min_specificity)].count()
```

but actually, i don't get how to include the 'checking' of the annotation column inside the code.

I could appreciate some guidance. !

Luis

Comment: Can you check your output please? I don't understand why S2=1?

Comment: done, sorry! it should be 0.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
>>> df[df['annotation'].eq(0)].filter(regex='S\d+').ge(0.9).sum().T
S1    1
S2    0
S3    0
dtype: int64
```

Steps:

1. keep only rows where `annotation == 0`
2. select only columns like `S<num>`
3. check if `S-values >= 0.9`
4. sum all (boolean) values
5. transpose your dataframe

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion.. so, the S1, S2, S3 are actually longer string like 'LQ-01-61-01.mzML' or 'Catha edulis|Leaves', i just put S1, S2, S3 to simplify the example. I don't think regex will work in this case no?

Comment: Not a problem. How do you want to select your column? Create a list of column names or use `.iloc` to select column numbers or anything else. Let me know it, I will update my answer.